# product to decrease c++ compile time?

Tags: c++, compile-time

Are there any products that will decrease c++ build times? that can be used with msvc?

Comment: See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373142/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-speed-up-c-compilation-times

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364240/how-do-you-reduce-compile-time-and-linking-time-for-visual-c-projects-native

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it has to be a product, look at [Xoreax IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com/), which distributes the build to machines on the network.

Other than that:

- solid build machines. RAM as it fits, use fast separate disks.
- Splitting into separate projects (DLLs, Libraries). They can build in parallel, too
  (use dual quad/core, and is easily bottlenecked by disk)
- Intelligent use of headers, including precompiled headers. That's not easy, and often there are other stakeholders.
  [PIMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) helps, too.

Answer (score 6):

Usage of [precompiled headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d87zb00(VS.71).aspx) might decrease your compile time.

Comment: Generally true, though they may *increase* build times

Answer (score 2):

Look at [MPCL](http://todobits.es/mpcl.html).

This is a plug-in for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 and Visual C++2008, which allow  to maximize the use of the CPU in order to minimize the compiling time of your project.

It compiles several .c / .cpp files of the same project in parallel in order to achieve it. This is specially usefull when you have a Dual core / Quad core / Multi core processor.

Comment: Or you could just use the built in /MP switch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx

Comment: Is MPCL faster or slower than IncrediBuild?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a shared build server? MSVC will run in a Terminal Server, and you can amortize the cost of CPUs, RAM and fast disks over the development team. As a side benefit, this Terminal Server can then also house the Version Control System, so checkouts are fast.