# #include all .cpp files into a single compilation unit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I recently had cause to work with some Visual Studio C++ projects with the usual Debug and Release configurations, but also 'Release All' and 'Debug All', which I had never seen before.

It turns out the author of the projects has a single ALL.cpp which #includes all other .cpp files. The *All configurations just build this one ALL.cpp file. It is of course excluded from the regular configurations, and regular configurations don't build ALL.cpp

I just wondered if this was a common practice? What benefits does it bring? (My first reaction was that it smelled bad.)

What kinds of pitfalls are you likely to encounter with this? One I can think of is if you have anonymous namespaces in your .cpps, they're no longer 'private' to that cpp but now visible in other cpps as well?

All the projects build DLLs, so having data in anonymous namespaces wouldn't be a good idea, right? But functions would be OK?

Comment: Definitely pathological; I can only guess at the reason why anyone might want to do that (if you, on the other hand, can ask them directly, you should). Normally in C++ you want to do the opposite, keep not only implementation files but also headers well separated. (A common trap of C++ projects being "#include spaghetti", with every header file depending on every other.) Perhaps to stress test the compiler ?

Comment: There is [a short video](http://oj.blackapache.net.s3.amazonaws.com/UnityBuilds.html) presenting the built-time difference in unitybuild.

Comment: An introduction on "Unity Builds" along with benefits, disadvantages and a complete CMake integration can be found at [cheind.wordpress.com](http://cheind.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/reducing-compilation-time-unity-builds/). hth, Christoph

Comment: Our official build always need a rebuild so I believe this approach could improve build performance a lot. But since the official builds are mainly consumed by Devs, but the UnityBuild generated pdbs maybe invalid for no-unitybuild code. (We don't want to develop with a unity build configuration, right?)

Comment: Completely different reason to include some implementation files into another implementation file is: these files can be autogenerated. It is much easier to autogenerate an entire file than dealing with changes injection into the existing code.

Comment: @Morendil: If a template is used in multiple compilation units, none of which know about the others, a linker may be able to throw out the redundant code, but it can't win back the time the compiler wasted generating it.  Merging the code from those compilation units into one would save the compiler from having to perform such redundant effort in the first place.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's referred to by some (and google-able) as a "Unity Build". It links insanely fast and compiles reasonably quickly as well. It's great for builds you don't need to iterate on, like a release build from a central server, but it isn't necessarily for incremental building.

And it's a PITA to maintain.

EDIT: here's the first google link for more info: http://buffered.io/posts/the-magic-of-unity-builds/

The thing that makes it fast is that the compiler only needs to read in everything once, compile out, then link, rather than doing that for every .cpp file.

Bruce Dawson has a much better write up about this on his blog: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/make-vc-compiles-fast-through-parallel-compilation/

Comment: It's not just because of I/O. Each single .cpp file often includes many header files. If you compile them separately, then you compile the code in the header files multiple times -- once for each .o file. If you use "Unity Build" then these header files and everything else is compiled only once.

Comment: Er... that falls under I/O. But yes, that's more precise.

Comment: Compiles are *not* usually I/O bound, unless you have insufficient memory. See my answer down below. The disk cache works. The linked-to post spends a lot of time on sophistry to explain how bad disk I/O is, but it is irrelevant because of the disk cache.

Also, *compiling* the code in the header files multiple times is completely different from I/O. The redundant compilation is the problem, the redundant I/O never actually happens.

Some of the perils of unity builds are covered here:
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/make-vc-compiles-fast-through-parallel-compilation/

Comment: I wonder if when using CMake you could have it generate the unity build .cpp file from the list of sources fed into a target.  After all, CMake already has all this information.  I also wonder how all this changes when using flash memory drives instead of spinning drives, but most people have already commented that the raw I/O isn't the problem, but rather the repeated compilation.  In a non-unity build, I certainly noticed an improvement with flash drives for the raw I/O.

Comment: one more thing - a unity build doesn't have to be done with one unity source file (for example a 100 file target may be built as 10 unity files each including 10 of the original ones). [https://github.com/sakra/cotire](https://github.com/sakra/cotire) gives you control over how many unity source files are used. Also check out [https://github.com/onqtam/ucm](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm) - a wrapper of cotire for easier usage of unity builds (and more).

Comment: @Frank's reason is the main reason for the slowness and it's mentioned here [Why does C++ compilation take so long?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/318398/995714)

Comment: edit queue currently full. I'd like to add [this link to info about pitfalls](https://engineering.leewinder.co.uk/2009/12/15/the-evils-of-unity-builds/) (unnamed namespaces, using declarations in cpp files, etc.). Also a link to [CMake feature support](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/UNITY_BUILD.html).

Answer (score 64):

Unity builds improved build speeds for three main reasons. The first reason is that all of the shared header files only need to be parsed once. Many C++ projects have a lot of header files that are included by most or all CPP files and the redundant parsing of these is the main cost of compilation, especially if you have many short source files. Precompiled header files can help with this cost, but usually there are a lot of header files which are not precompiled.

The next main reason that unity builds improve build speeds is because the compiler is invoked fewer times. There is some startup cost with invoking the compiler.

Finally, the reduction in redundant header parsing means a reduction in redundant code-gen for inlined functions, so the total size of object files is smaller, which makes linking faster.

Unity builds can also give better code-gen.

Unity builds are *NOT* faster because of reduced disk I/O. I have profiled many builds with xperf and I know what I'm talking about. If you have sufficient memory then the OS disk cache will avoid the redundant I/O - subsequent reads of a header will come from the OS disk cache. If you don't have enough memory then unity builds could even make build times worse by causing the compiler's memory footprint to exceed available memory and get paged out.

Disk I/O is expensive, which is why all operating systems aggressively cache data in order to avoid redundant disk I/O.

Comment: Most correct answer here. For massive projects there is no alternative for build speed. BTW suggested msbuild /LTCG increase link time from 4 minutes to overnight! (Clang was better).

Comment: Note that VS 2015 fixes the bug listed below which makes LTCG links run significantly faster - three times faster on some recent large-scale tests.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1064219/ltcg-linking-of-chromes-pdf-dll-spends-60-of-time-in-c2-dll-ssrfree

Comment: Correct. C++ compilation is slow because each compilation unit must be compiled separately [Why does C++ compilation take so long?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/318398/995714)

Answer (score 7):

I wonder if that ALL.cpp is attempting to put the entire project within a single compilation unit, to improve the ability for the compiler to optimize the program for size?

Normally some optimizations are only performed within distinct compilation units, such as removal of duplicate code and inlining.

That said, I seem to remember that recent compilers (Microsoft's, Intel's, but I don't think this includes GCC) can do this optimization across multiple compilation units, so I suspect that this 'trick' is unneccessary.

That said, it would be curious to see if there is indeed any difference.

Comment: Visual C++ can do whole program optimization with the /LTCG switch (link-time code generation)

Comment: these days, GCC and clang also support LTO

Comment: Then it's certainly unnecessary.

Comment: This redices the SPEED and Hard disk Drive head movements A LOT!

Comment: Петър Петров: Do you have any benchmarks that indicate this?  It should *increase* speed because it means that there is no need to recursively and repeatedly visit, open, and parse header files.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Bruce; from my experience I had tried implementing the Unity Build for one of my .dll projects which had a ton of header includes and lots of .cpps; to bring down the overall Compilation time on the VS2010(had already exhausted the Incremental Build options) but rather than cutting down the Compilation time, I ran out of memory and the Build not even able to finish the Compilation.

However to add; I did find enabling the Multi-Processor Compilation option in Visual Studio quite helps in cutting down the Compilation time; I am not sure if such an option is available across other platform compilers.

Comment: If you agree and aren't adding anything, it doesn't seem like this should be an answer.  This sounds like more of a story and comment.

Comment: Actually; I intended to add a comment about my own experience with the issue(on an industrial strength & sized code-base); for someone trying the same because the idea of Unity Builds kind of gives the impression that it would almost result in lesser Compilation; which isn't the case for large projects. The reason why we would be trying this in the first place; but I am nobody to rule out exceptions and certain design considerations.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bruce Dawson's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22444654/3162383) the following link brings more insights onto the pros and cons of unity builds - https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#unity-builds

Answer (score 0):

We have a multi platform project for MacOS and Windows. We have lots of large templates and many headers to include. We halfed build time with Visual Studio 2017 msvc using precompiled headers. For MacOS we tried several days to reduce build time but precompiled headers only reduced build time to 85%. Using a single .cpp-File was the breakthrough. We simply create this ALL.cpp with a script. Our ALL.cpp contains a list of includes of all .cpp-Files of our project. We reduce build time to 30% with XCode 9.0. The only drawback was we had to give names to all private unamed compilation unit namespaces in .cpp-Files. Otherwise the local names will clash.