# How to display the number of remaining files in build time in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to display number of remaining files in build time in Visual Studio 2015.
I can use distributed build system, but the build time is going to longer if there are only a few files which needs to be compiled.

So what I want to do is first try to build the project on my PC, then if there are a lot files need to be compiled then I will just switch to DBS.
(It is even better if I can know the number of files which need to be compiled before I even try to build the project)

It is a c++ project.

Comment: Try looking: [MSBuild / Visual Studio distributed builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681677/msbuild-visual-studio-distributed-builds)...

Comment: thanks for the reply.
I already have a DBS (SN-DBS).
What I want to know is, when I build my project, which one (no DB or DB) would be faster.
e.g.
if there are 10 files need to be compiled, normal building would be faster
but if there are 1000 files need to be compiled then DBS would be faster.