# Do Warnings slow C++ Compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, teamcity, cl.exe

Do compiler warnings slow down the compilation process? For my purposes I am specifically looking at C++ compilation, using cl.exe via Team City.

Robert Greiner's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1539364/210566) indicates that warnings do make a difference to compilation speed, but there seems to be no consensus or confirmation link.

As background, the code I've inherited generates 606 warnings.

Comment: Rather focus on fixing these warnings

Comment: "Improving the build time" would be a great business justification for fixing those warnings.

Comment: Warnings slow the programmer who is looking at the compiler output.

Comment: Agreed, though I'd not like this question to turn into a discussion on the merits of clearing up warnings (we all know it's the right thing to do).

Comment: Yes, any output to the screen or terminal slows down the compilation process.  So get rid of them by changing your code!

Comment: The number of warnings needs to have a lines of code (LOC) account or it could be misinterpreted (such as 606 warnings for 10 lines of code versus 606 warnings for 6000 lines of code).

Comment: In clang warnings/errors slow down compilation much more significantly than in Visual C++, although the error messages in clang are excellent. Producing useful warning/error messages takes significant effort for compiler developers especially in case of a screwed up language as C++. I'm pretty sure that dumping error messages to stdout/stderr already slows down the compilation but processing/producing the error messages also takes time especially in case of clang.