# Using runtime interface at compile time

Tags: c++, machine-learning, compile-time

I need hardware support (it might be FPGA) at compile time to speed up compile-time computations. To be more specific compile-time training of a neural network. This might use OpenCL to greatly speed up compilation.

Would a compiler provide such an ability?

The best would be ability to call custom dynamic library function at compile-time.

I prefer C++. I see LLVM is moving forward pretty fast.

Does it provide something similar to enable it in Clang?

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. Could precomputing the data work for your use case?

Comment: [What are ways of improving build/compile time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1539347/995714), [What techniques can be used to speed up C++ compilation times?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/373142/995714)

Comment: You should explain what actual *compile-time computations* you need to speedup. Perhaps show some code. And certainly you should **edit your question** to improve it (probably by adding several paragraphs motivating your question).

Comment: Sergei, please edit your question to improve it and motivate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need hardware support (it might be FPGA) at compile time to speed up compile-time computations.

Compile-time computations are generally not that intensive. (and it is a *quality of implementation* issue). So it is unlikely you'll find that.

Perhaps you can use plugins for your compiler (e.g. [plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) in C++ for GCC, or extensions using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), or [plugins](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html) in C++ for Clang), and add for example extra compiler builtins thru them.

Or simply, generate some C or C++ code thru some *external* tool.

<sup>(maybe you are looking for hardware support in your compiler to speed up the run time of your compiled program, so you want a compiler able to take advantage of your hardware for the generated code, but that is a very *different* question)</sup>