# Why do we include header files and not source files?

Tags: c++

Here is an example. If I declared a function in a header file named `Bob.h`: `void PrintSomething();` and in the `.cpp` file I say: `void MyClass::PrintSomething(){std::cout << "Hello";}` . I've seen people in another `.cpp` file for example `Frank.cpp`, only include the `Bob.h` header which just has the declaration (No code inside it) and not the `.cpp` with the code but then what blows my mind is when they call the `PrintSomething()` function in `Frank.cpp` it uses the code from `Bob.cpp` and prints "Hello". How? How does it print "Hello" which was added in the `.cpp` file when I've only included the `.h` file which doesn't say anything about "Hello", its just a declaration? I've looked through the compile process and linking process too but it just doesn't stick.

On top of which if I were to now say in my `Frank.cpp` file: `void MyClass::PrintSomething(){std::cout << "Bye";}` and included the `Bob.h` file in my `main.cpp` and called the `PrintSomething()` function would it print "Hello" or "Bye"? Is the computer psychic or something? This concept is the one thing I am not grasping in my C++ learning journey.

Comment: "How does it print "Hello" which was added in the .cpp file when I've only included the .h file which doesn't say anything about "Hello", its just a declaration?" thats the linkers job.

Comment: " I've looked through the compile process and linking process too"  Take a closer look at linking.

Comment: "would it print "Hello" or "Bye"?" im pretty sure you would get a linker erreor from having 2 definitions of the same function

Comment: BTW the linker is doing the same job with your functions that it does with library functions.  Compiling your program would be really slow if there were no separate linker, because the system header files would have to contain the complete definitions of all library functions and the compiler would have to re-optimize the whole library for each change you make to your code.  Avoiding that is the point of having multiple compilation units linked together.

Comment: Also, it is possible to include other source units, doing so is called a "Unity Build".  discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/847974/103167

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The moment you include `Bob.h` the compiler has everything it needs to know about `PrintSomething()`, it only need a declaration of the function. `Frank.cpp` does not need to know about `Bob.cpp` which defines `PrintSomething()`.

All of your individual `cpp` files output object files generated by the compiler. These in themselves don't do much until they're all glued together, this is the linker's responsibility.

The linker takes all your object files and fills in the missing parts:

Linker talk:

> Hey, I see that `Frank.obj` uses `PrintSomething()` and I can't see
> its definition in that object file.
>
> Let's check the other object files..
>
> Upon inspecting `Bob.obj` I can see that this contains a usable
> definition for `PrintSomething()`, let's use that.

This is of course simplified but that's what a linker does in short.

After this is done you get your usable executable.

---

> on top of which if I were to now say in my Frank.cpp file: `void MyClass::PrintSomething(){std::cout << "Bye";}` and included the `Bob.h`
> file in my `main.cpp` and called the `PrintSomething()` function would it
> print "Hello" or "Bye"? Is the computer psychic or something?

The linker would find 2 definitions of `PrintSomething()` and would emit an error, it has no way to know what definition is the right one to pick.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful explanation. The "Linker Talk" is the level which I can process how this works so perfecto lmao.

Answer (score 0):

The key notion here is **separate compilation**. You divide your project into a set of source files that implement more-or-less independent things, you compile those source files into object files, and you link the object files and any additional libraries (including the standard library) to create an executable file. For large projects, compiling all of the source files can take a long time (sometimes measured in hours). The first time you build your application you have to do that. But after that, if you only changed one source file you only need to recompile that source file and then link again, which the object files that you created the first time through. That's usually a big time saver. If you have one massive source file (i.e., a source file that `#include`s all the rest of your source files), you don't get that option -- you have to recompile the whole thing every time.