# How to optimize building speed in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, build

Could someone give me tips to increase building speed in visual studio 2008?
I have a large project with many module with full source. Every single time it's built, every files are rebuilt, some of them were not changed. Can i prevent these file to be rebuilt?
I turned the property "Enable Minimum rebuild" /Gm on but the compiler threw this warning

```
Command line warning D9030 : '/Gm' is incompatible with multiprocessing; ignoring /MP switch
```

Every tips to increase building speed will help me much.
Thanks,

Comment: Are you saying you - build all, change nothing, and build all again will recompile stuff?

Comment: Xoreax Incredibuild, while not cheap, helps a lot. We regularly get speedups of > 10x.That said, broken dependencies still hurt a lot because it forces an expensive relink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is to compile in debug mode(aka zero optimizations), this of course is only for internal testing.

you can also use precompiled headers* to speed up processing, or break off 'unchanging' segments into static libs, removing those from the recompile.

*with `/MP` you need to create the precompiled header before doing multiprocess compilation, as `/MP` can read but not write according to MSDN

Comment: In my experience compiling in debug mode is much slower because writing the debug information produces much more disk activity.

Comment: @fschmitt: you do know you can compile in debug mode and have it not generate that info, its (almost) the same as compiling in release with no optimizations, either way accomplishes what I meant, removing expensive optimization time, and it doesn't make any other the other points any less true....

Answer (score 16):

C++ compile times are a battle for every project above a certain size. Luckily, with so many people writing large C++ projects, there are a variety of solutions:

The classic cheap solution is the "unity build". This just means using `#include` to put all of your .cpp files into a single file for compilation. "Unity build" has come up in a number of questions here on stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543697/include-all-cpp-files-into-a-single-compilation-unit) is the most prominent one that I'm aware of. This [screencast](http://buffered.io/posts/screencast-setting-up-unity-builds/) demonstrates how to set up such a build in Visual Studio.

My understanding is that unity builds are much faster than classic builds because they effectively cache work done by the preprocessor and linker. One drawback to the unity build is that if you touch one cpp file you'll have to recompile your "big" cpp file. You can work around this by breaking the cpp file you're iterating on out of the unity build and compiling it on its own.

Beyond Unity builds, here's a list of my best practices:

- Use `#include` only when neccessary, prefer forward declarations
- Use the pimpl idiom to keep class implementation out of commonly included header files. Doing so allows you to add members to an implementation without suffering a long recompile
- Make use of precompiled headers (pch) for commonly included header files that change rarely
- Make sure that your build system is using all of the cores available on the local hardware
- Keep the list of directories the preprocessor has to search minimal, use precise paths in `#include` statements
- Use `#pragma once` at the top of header files instead of `#ifndef __FOO_H #define __FOO_H ... #endif`, if you use the `#ifndef` trick the compiler will have to open the header file each time it is included, `#pragma once` allows the compiler to be more efficient

If you're doing all that (the unity build will make the biggest difference, in my experience), the last option is distributed building. [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/) is the best free solution I'm aware of, [incredibuild](http://www.incredibuild.com/) is the proprietary industry standard. I'm of the opinion that distributed computing is going to be the only way to get great iteration times out of the messy C++ compilation process. If you have access to a reasonably large number of machines (say, 10-20) this is totally worth looking into. I should mention that unity builds and distributed builds are not totally symbiotic because a traditional compile can be split into smaller chunks of work than a unity build. If you want to go distributed, it's probably not worth setting up a unity build.

Comment: For the order of #pragma once and include guard, I observed that (1)Microsoft put #pragma after include guard (2) Even #pragma comes after include guard,  compiler can also skip openning the file. My test based on VC2010+SP1, I use /showincludes and procmon to investigate such issue.

Answer (score 6):

`Enable Minimal Build`:`/Gm` is incompatible with `Build with Multiple Processes`:`/MP{<cores>}`
Thus you can only use one of these two at a time.

> /Gm > Project's Properties : **Configuration Properties** > **C/C++** > **CodeGeneration**
>   or
>   /MP{n} > Project's Properties : **Configuration Properties** > **C/C++** > **Command Line**

---

Also to prevent unnecessary builds (of untouched files) - structure your code *properly*; Follow this rule:

> In the  [**`.h`**] header files, place **only what's needed** by the contents of the header file itself;
>   and all that you need to share across multiple execution units.
>
> The rest goes in the implementation [**`.c`** / **`.cpp`**] files.

Comment: OK, but which of the 2 one should prefer? If they are mutually exclusive, how come Microsoft didn't simply keep the best one?

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide more information on the structure of your project and which files are being rebuilt?
Unchanged C++ files may be rebuilt because they include header files that have been changed, in that case /Gm option will not help

Comment: Our project has some external open sources projects.

Answer (score 2):

Rebuilding all files after changing one header file is a common problem.  The solution is to closely examine what #include your header files use and remove all that can be removed.  If your code only uses pointers and references to a class, you can replace

```
#include "foo.h"
```

with

```
class Foo;
```