# Is it possible to get g++ to only preprocess includes?

Tags: c++, g++

I have written a project that is designed to be a single header include. Since I have written many smaller files that do specific things it would be easier to have a preprocessor only process the includes so that everything can be combined into one file with the other preprocessor statements NOT executed. Is this possible with g++?

I have used the command g++ file.h -E -P -o file.i but this preprocesses all of the preprocessor statements

Comment: The preprocessor preprocesses. It sounds like you just want to concatenate all files into a single file. Can't you just use `cat` for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge C++ files into a single source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995773/merge-c-files-into-a-single-source-file)

Comment: Given that some files may be included only if a macro is defined, this is logically impossible.   In such cases the preprocessor needs to test/expand macros before deciding whether to `#include` a file.   More generally, the preprocessor runs through sequentially from beginning to end - it doesn't do one phase of including files then another of expanding macros.   It does whatever is needed on each line, based on what has come before, and then continues to the next

Comment: @Peter: That would make a perfect Answer.