# Visual Studio warning about copies of files with different contents

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I go to debug my C++ project in Visual Studio, up pops a little warning dialogue box that tells me:

```
A copy of datum.h was found in
c:/users/brad/desktop/source/binary/datum.h, but the current
source code is different from the version built into
c:/users/brad/desktop/source/binary/datum.h.
```

I'm having trouble understanding what this is even trying to tell me, let alone how to fix it. At first I thought it might be complaining that I'd accidentally duplicated a file in the directory, which I checked, and found nothing of the sort, which leaves me pretty stumped. I also tried excluding the file from the solution and adding it again, which didn't fix the problem either.

The warning doesn't appear to actually hinder the development of my project, but I suppose warnings exist for a reason, so if anyone knows what's gone wrong, any advice would be greatly appreciated. To my knowledge, I didn't change anything to cause the message to appear, it just popped up one time I went to debug the solution and has kept on appearing ever since.

Also, more copies of the same warning have started popping up, pertaining to other header files in my solution (I haven't recieved any about .cpp files yet, but it could be a coincidence, because it's only been going on for about 20 minutes).

Comment: [You are not alone.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fc14870d-60b2-4701-abd0-fe541ac90e72/release-mode-file-sync-issue-current-source-code-different-from-the-version-built?forum=toolsforwinapps)

Comment: Hmm interesting. I didn't find anything on Google. What did you search to find that?

Comment: Literal messages (omitting the particular file and variable names, of course) are usually the best bet. In this case, I searched for ["but the current source code is different from the version built into"](https://www.google.es/search?q="but+the+current+source+code+is+different+from+the+version+built+into").

Comment: There are even [two results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22the+current+source+code+is+different+from+the+version%22) in this site, but to find them you need to omit "but", because the two posters didn't bother to paste the full message: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22685026/96780), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27106626/96780).

Comment: In my case I had multiple projects in the solution and I had forgotten to change the *Startup Project* in the Solution Explorer before starting the new project file from the editor. The two projects had the same `MainWindow` class (no difference could be seen on the screen). VS was comparing the file in the editor (belonging to the new project) with the one stored in the old project which was still the Startup Project and which was the one actually launched.

Comment: microsoft for ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you by any chance be debugging another executable (not the one actually built?). This is a common issue in scenarios where Visual Studio builds the binaries in one directory but then they are copied over to some other directory for debugging. I'd suggest you compare the target path under the debugging settings and the output directory under the general settings in Visual Studio.

[image: TargetPath]

This would explain the issue, since you are actually debugging some older version of the binary (not the one built currently) and thus the warning, since Visual Studio can't find the version of the source files for that version of the binary.

Comment: I managed to make the warning disappear by running the Clean operation on the solution. I'm not sure about the semantics of the operation so I imagine it would have done something similar to what you suggested. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @BradSullivan well, if it comes back, make a comment, we can try to sort it out:) There are not that many reasons it can come from.

Comment: **If this doesn't work for you, [see my answer below](/a/64637231/541686)!**

Answer (score 51):

Try removing breakpoints from the file in question.
This worked for me when it occurred with Visual Studio 2013 for a header file in debug build.
[Source: Release mode file sync issue - current source code different from the version built](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fc14870d-60b2-4701-abd0-fe541ac90e72/release-mode-file-sync-issue-current-source-code-different-from-the-version-built?forum=toolsforwinapps)

Additional notes: Clean / Rebuild also works, but that is painful for regularly changing code.  Enabling the break point after starting debugger merely delays the message.

Comment: I have had this keep happening even after a clean rebuild. This is with VS 2015. My guess is perhaps the debugger and the compiler disagree on how to hash newlines or something like that? The fix is to turn off "require source files to exactly match the original version" in Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Comment: I had breakpoints in the .H file that it was barking at (set on inline functions), running the debugger in VS2013. I removed the breakpoints and the nag message no longer appeared.

Comment: deleting all breakpoints fixed the issue for me.   I had one on the header file being flagged.  Great tip.

Comment: All this does is hide the issue, it still comes up you'll still be unable to step through it... -1

Answer (score 22):

I solved it:

1. Close the window of the .h file in Visual Studio if it's open.
2. Close Visual Studio.
3. CUT the .h file from its normal location and paste it into a temporary folder that VS doesn't know about.
4. Restart VS and compile. It'll complain about the missing .h file.  Good -- Make the bastard beg for it!
5. Paste the .h file back into its original location.
6. Compile.  VS will gratefully accept the missing file.  (Damn I hate Microsoft!)

Comment: This still doesn't prevent the problem from happening again (i.e. it still happens the next time you edit the file).

Answer (score 9):

### This occurs if you rename an implementation file (*.c, *.cpp, etc.) to a header file.

This is because the **Item Type** still remains as `C/C++ Source File`, making it get compiled as a separate translation unit rather than as an actual header, preventing Visual Studio from recognizing its inclusion as a header elsewhere.

It took me quite a while to figure this out.

To fix this:

1. Right-click your header file in Solution Explorer and select Properties.
2. Select *All Configurations*, *All Platforms*.
3. Under General, change *Item Type* to `C/C++ Header`.
4. Press OK.
5. Force-recompile any file that `#include`s your header (or just `Rebuild` the solution).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the debugger thinks that the checksum of the source file is different from what the compiler calculated and put in there. The debugger will then refuse to apply breakpoints in the files that mis-match, to prevent you from seeing data it can't guarantee is correct.

I have had this keep happening even after a clean rebuild. This is with VS 2015. My guess is perhaps the debugger and the compiler disagree on how to hash newlines or something like that? The fix is to turn off "require source files to exactly match the original version" in Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Comment: The difference may be more than just whitespaces!

Answer (score 2):

The reason may be circular header dependencies. datum.h may includes another_header.h (directly or indirectly), which includes datum.h.

Answer (score 1):

I see the real reason of this question is not answered. So for someone still looking, here it goes... 
     The most common reason of this problem is that the source files used to build the existing obj files are different than the existing ones. In other words the 
particular project did not build after new modifications to source. The solution to this problem is to rebuild the project after modifying. 
     This happened to me in situation where I had modified my static library projects files and then without building that project I started my application project which was using this static library project.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

- close VS
- delete `*.vcxproj.filters` file
- restart VS

problem should be gone.

Comment: Nope it isn't gone, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**this worked for me:**

1. clean project
2. debug/delete all breakpoints :)

Comment: This only fixes it one time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (as of March 2019):

1. Click the 'Build' drop-down menu in the top left of your Visual Studio window
2. Select 'Rebuild Solution'

Comment: This only fixes it one time.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the file name and it works now.

Comment: This is a red herring, it's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this.  In my case, one of my `.h` files contained implementation (a class with static methods), which was #included by one of my `.cpp` files, but the Project Settings were also telling Visual Studio to compile the `.h` file.

I manually edited both the `.vcxproj` and `.vcxproj.filters` project files, moving the `.h` file from the `<ClCompile>` ItemGroup to the `<ClInclude>` ItemGroup.

This did the trick for me; I never saw the "*A copy of...is different from...*" pop-up again.
(Note that this was after I had thoroughly failed in attempts to get `<DependentUpon>` to work.)

Answer (score 0):

My solutiion:

1. Build -> Configuration manager
2. Switch to another configuration (any, example Releas or Debug)
3. Switch to previous configuration

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple projects, each with their own entry point within a solution. Make sure that the correct project is being run.

The `source code is different` message can appear in a project A's source when you are running project B. In this case, the message can mean `This breakpoint won't be hit because you're running a project that doesn't include it`

Answer (score 0):

This message may appear after setting a breakpoint and starting a debug session. It's not always clear why, particularly in a debug build where there should be no optimisations, however it's a warning rather than an error. You can continue debugging after dismissing the warning.

You can enable/disable the warning for individual breakpoints by hovering over the breakpoint icon in the editor and clicking its settings (gear) icon. A peek window will appear in the editor. Select the hyperlink at the top of this window and check/uncheck the **Allow the source code to be different from the original** option.

To disable for all breakpoints, go to **Debug > Options and Settings**. On the **Debugging/General** page, clear the **Require source files that exactly match the original version** option. Make sure to reenable this option when you're finished debugging.

More info:
[Troubleshoot Breakpoints in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/debuggers/troubleshooting-breakpoints)