# Visual Studio 2012 is slow when selecting items in the solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After having installed "Visual Studio 2012 **Update1**" some new buttons have been added, but unfortunately Solution Explorer has become incredibly slow. All mouse events on it (click, right click, double-click, on either the toolbar or any item) requires 5-10 seconds before having an answer.

*After having un-installed update1 speed returned normal*(=immediate).

Maybe one possible cause is one of the new buttons added, maybe "Show on Code Map".
Unfortunately I can find no way to customize (remove buttons from) Solution Explorer Toolbar; there is no "Show on Code Map" extension installed.
I have no ideas on how to investigate further.

As at least one guy got the same problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387146/visual-studio-2012-is-slow-when-selecting-item-in-the-solution-explorer)) maybe someone has the solution or ideas on how to further investigate.

Thank you
Stefano

Using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1

---

UPDATE:
Microsoft released Visual Studio 2012 **Update 2**;
now, with Update 2 installed, everything has returned 'normal speed',
so this question can be considered closed/obsolete. :-)

Comment: How large is your solution, how many projects and files? What language(s) is it using?

Comment: It is always good to start from disabling extensions you have installed. After this you can try to launch devenv.exe /resetsettings (this will reset settings in your IDE, so if you have specific one, save them first).

Comment: Solution has vb.net and C# projects. A total of 95 projects.

Comment: @outcoldman: The installed extensions are: Microsoft Web Developer Tools, Nuget Package Manager, Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor, Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript. A strange but positive behaviour is that Solution Explorer events are becoming **each day quicker** ! So in a month the problem may become irrilevant; from the day I asked the question the NuGet Package has been updated and maybe this makes the difference !

Comment: Try my advice in [the following answer][1], starting with removing an *.suo file.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19277877/90475