# enum in header causes excessive recompilations

Tags: c++, c

> John Lakos refers to this problem as *an insidious source of
>   compile-time coupling* (Figure 0-3, in his Introduction):

The problem I am facing is that too many files get compiled because there is a physical dependency on a single enum.

I have a header with the enum definition:

```
// version.h
enum Version {
    v1 = 1,
    v2, v3, v4, v5, ... v100
};
```

and this is used by hundreds of files.
Each file defines a class of objects, which have to be read from the disk,
using the `read()` function. `Version` is used to determine the way data is to be read.

Every time a new class or class member is introduced, a new entry is appended to the enum

```
// typeA.cpp
#include "version.h"

void read (FILE *f, ObjectA *p, Version v) 
{
    read_float(f, &p->x);
    read_float(f, &p->y);
    if (v >= v100) { 
        read_float(f, &p->z);  // after v100 ObjectA becomes a 3D
    }
}
```

and

```
// typeB.cpp
#include "version.h"

void read (FILE *f, ObjectB *p, Version v)
{
    read_float (f, &p->mass);
    if (v >= v30) {
        read_float (f, &p->velocity);
    }
    if (v >= v50) {
        read_color (f, &p->color);
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see, once `ObjectA` changes, we have to introduce  a new entry (say `v100`) to the `Version`. Consequently all `type*.cpp` files will be compiled, even though only `read()` of `ObjectA` really needs the `v100` entry.

**How can I invert the dependency on the enum, with minimal changes to the client (i.e. `type*.cpp`) code, so that only the necessary .c files compile ?**

Here is a possible solution, that I thought of, but I need a better one:

I was thinking that I could put the enum in a .cpp file, and expose `int`s with the values of the respective enum members:

```
//version.cpp
enum eVersion {
    ev1 = 1,
    ev2, ev3, ev4, ev5, ... ev100
};

const int v1 = ev1;
const int v2 = ev2;
....
const int v100 = ev100;   // introduce a new global int for every new entry in the enum
```

make an alias for the `Version` type somehow

```
//version.h
typedef const int Version;
```

and introduce only the const int values that are needed each time:

```
// typeA.cpp
#include "version.h"

extern Version v100;    ///// *** will be resolved at link time

void read (FILE *f, ObjectA *p, Version v) 
{
    read_float(f, &p->x);
    read_float(f, &p->y);
    if (v >= v100) { 
        read_float(f, &p->z);  // after v100 ObjectA becomes a 3D
    }
}
```

but I think this looks like very poor solution, which dates back to pre-header times

Comment: Could you just use an integer instead of the enum, and use eg. `if (v >= 30) {` instead of `if (v >= v30) {`?

Comment: In any case, there is no real dependency on `version.h`, unless an edit *re-orders* the enum, which seems like it would be outside of the anticipated behaviour (and thus cause for `make clean`).

Comment: @Dmitri the labels (like v30) are more complicated, and do not easily translate to numbers. I used v1-v100 for simplicity

Comment: Well, each of your other files gets recompiled because it `#include`s a file you've modified, not because they use the enum per se.  But if you can't either get rid of the `#include` or stop modifying that header (or dependencies of that header), the problem will persist.  You could split the `read` functions to different source files so that less code gets recompiled, I guess.

Comment: Who is John Lakos, what are you citing and where is the figure the author is talking about?

Comment: @ChristianHackl : He's the author of the classic book 'Large Scale C++ Software Design'. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2088514

Comment: @Dmitri this is not an effective solution. Every day, one of 100 programmers changes one of 600 of these type*.cpp files, causing 600 files to recompile for each of the 100 programmers. I really need to take this number down to 1-2 files.

Comment: @ChristianHackl here's a free copy for you... http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs190/2008/documents/lakos/chapter0.pdf

Comment: Use macros instead of enum labels, and multiple headers (one per version, eg. version_v1.h, version_v2.h, etc.).  Each header can #include the previous and define its macro in terms of the previous (eg. `#include "version_v29.h"` then `#define v30 (v29+1)`, and each source file can include just the header for the minimum version it requires.  That way only sources needing a new version depend on a new or changed header.  Of course, that could make a lot of work for the preprocessor..

Comment: @Dmitri (+1) good idea if you don't mind about exploding the enum into many files. Unfortunately there is a reason for the enum, in that it keeps all the relevant entries together. If you allow to create one file for each version, the chain might be broken accidentally into 2 tails, and you might never see it. The entries in the enum are helpful, because if 2 programmers try to create a new Version entry, the VCS will stop due to the conflict in code

Comment: If you're using GNU make, try it with `-o version.h`?

Comment: @Dmitri you mean like `g++ typeA.cpp -o version.h` ?  what's that good for ? Can you try to clarify your suggestion please ?

Comment: Not `-o` for *g++*, `-o` for *make*... it makes make treat the file as if it were old, so other targets won't get rebuilt because it has changed (at least according to the docs... I haven't used that feature personally).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your versioning system. Can't you decouple the objects definitions from the reading?

```
// ObjectA.cpp

#include"ObjectA.h"  

// define ObjectA

void ObjectA::setPar ( float xx, float yy, float zz) 
{
    x = v[0];
    y = v[1];
    z = v[2]; 
}
```

then

```
// typeB.cpp

#include"ObjectB.h"  

// define ObjectB

void ObjectB::setPar ( float mm, float vv, color cc) 
{
    mass = mm;
    velocity = vv;
    color = cc; 
}
```

then in one (big) file

```
// readObject.cpp

#include"version.h"
#include"ObjectA.h"
#include"ObjectB.h"

void read (FILE *f, ObjectA *p, Version v) 
{
    float x,y,z;
    read_float(f, x);
    read_float(f, y);
    if (v >= v100) { 
        read_float(f, z);  // after v100 ObjectA becomes a 3D
    } else z=0.0;          // whatever
    p->setPar(x,y,z);
}

void read (FILE *f, ObjectB *p, Version v)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then I couple this file with *all* the "ObjectXXX.h" files. I will have reduced the effect of change on "version.h" on the system, but "readObject.cpp" will have thousands more reasons to recompile. However, there *are* gains with this method.

Comment: @Grim Fandango: Yes, but at least it is 1 file.. All the untoched ObjectX.cpp would not recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the enum in a separate .cfg file, as configuration data, then each of the other source files reads that configuration file.

Then when the configuration file is changed, no re-compile is needed.

All the other files read/parse the configuration file.

This is the classic method of handling such info.

Note: the configuration file would not contain an enum but rather certain formatted data.

Comment: By "each of the other source files reads that configuration file", I suppose you mean that the functions in each source file read the configuration file *at run time*, or something to that general effect.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly, each source file opens the configuration file for reading, reads the contents, parses the contents, uses the contents

Comment: Can you provide an example for that please ? I am not sure I follow.