# does adding a value at the end to a c++ enum defined in an header force recompilation?

Tags: c++, enums

**Background**

There is a complex system with several libraries and applications in it, pretty much every project depends upon an header file (foo.h for example) that defines an enum (#included in the several cpp files). The design is far to be ideal (but as usual it is a legacy system).

Sadly, foo.h changes pretty often.

**Prerequisite**

Let's say that we can guarantee that foo.h will be updated: only adding element at the end, without removing existing values nor redefining them.

**Questions**

Does such modification requires recompilation of all the code that includes the header? I am aware that this is a common problem with classes (typically removing an unused variable changes the memory layout and cause eventually a core dump). I suspect that can be a similar situation with enums as well, and in normal situation I will surely recompile everything anyway.
The current situation introduce a rigidity in all code base that hugely affects the way of the system is evolving.

I would like to know if I "have to" recompile. This information can be used to device the refactoring strategy.

**NOTE**

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655770/enum-in-header-causes-excessive-recompilations), but I don't think it is actually answering mine.

Comment: If the header is `#include` to any .c file that is included in your compiler build commands, then yes, it should result in a recompile.

Comment: Looking at the header funny will cause a recompile. Whatever you add to the header isn't actually a part of the program until you recompile. If the contents of this header are so volatile, have you considered changing this enum to something like a list which you can load from a file or db table?

Comment: @KennyOstrom : or more simply be defined in a .cpp file.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks, I am fairly new in the team, the current situation grew in years. The company works in latency sensitive field, so for that reason a compile time solution was preferred. I am making the case that the drawbacks are far more important of the cons. I am gathering information in that direction.

Comment: In practical terms the answer is: no, you don't "have to" recompile. You can make doubly sure that the length stays with `enum myEnum : int{val1,val2};`. But any typical build-system will trigger a recompile on a changed file and if you want to actually use any of the new enum-values by name you of course will need to recompile the files that use the new values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default answer is: if the contents of your translation unit (= preprocessed source file) changes, you have to recompile it to keep its object file in sync with its source form.

A change in a header file which is `#include`d results in a change in the preprocessed source of the translation unit, so it has to be recompiled to be fully in sync. So from this point of view, a change in the header requires a recompilation.

---

However, that is the most conservative approach. (And if anything goes wrong with any trickier approach, you should fall back to it). In practice, you may not *need* to recompile if all you did was add an enumerator to an enumeration.

If you introduce a new enumerator `e42` into the header but do not actually use it anywhere in file `x.cpp`, it's very likely that the object file produced from `x.cpp` with `e42` defined will be 100% identical to the object file produced from `x.cpp` without `e42` defined. So from this point of view, the recompilation is pointless. Ideally, you'd only want to recompile the source file if the generated object file will differ from the pre-change one.

Assuming you do not use the new enumerator in the file, then pretty much the only thing that can force an object file change is this: the size of the enumeration type can change. If your largest enumerator value is 2147483647, and you add a new one, it's quite possible that the size of the enumeration itself will jump from 32 bits to 64 bits.

You can get around this limitation by using C++11's ability to explicitly specify the underlying type of an enumeration. Make sure you specify it for the enumeration which you're extending like that.

```
enum EnumerationBeingExtended : int
//                            ^^^^^ this part
{
  // ... list of enumerators as before
};
```

If you have enumeration size (actually entire underlying type) fixed like that, it's very likely that the object files which only contain the old definition of the enumeration (the one without `e42`) will work just fine with object files containing the new one (the one with `e42`).

Of course, you will technically be in ill-formed program territory, because the program will violate the One Definition Rule (different translation units have a different definition of that enumeration). However, if all you do is use the enumeration values, you will likely be perfectly safe in practice.

I would be wary of this trick if you do funky stuff like using `typeid` on the enumeration type. But if you're only using the enumerators and the enumeration type itself "normally," you should be good.

Of course, you should ideally isolate this enumeration to a header file containing only that, and document its intended use heavily. You will also probably have to actually make allowances in your buildsystem for not rebuilding the file because of that header's change.

In summary: formally, you'll have an ill-formed program. But in practice, you should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If the challenge is to avoid as many recompilations as possible when changing the contents of an enum, there is a way that might work for you.

Forward declaration.

In foo.h:

```
enum class MyEnums : int;
```

In foo2.h (actually, I don't know what file name would be appropriate to call this file, but all it'll contain is the following):

```
enum class MyEnums : int
{
  Apple,
  Orange,
  Banana,
};
```

You typically won't need the definitions of your ever-changing enums in header files. The only two times I can see it happening are when you're including implementation details in the header or when you're naming default inputs. If it's the former, now's a good time to move those implementations to their .cpp file (unless they're templates...). So, usually only your .cpp files will include foo2 to get the definitions consistently and the header files that need it will get the forward-declared enum.

This'll still force the recompilation of any cpp files that include foo2, but any header files that include foo won't have to be recompiled as a result. And if they don't have to be recompiled, the things that include them don't have to be recompiled. And if *they* don't have to be recompiled, the things which include *them* don't have to be recompiled, etc. etc.

Usually slow building times in a large codebase come because someone changed a header that had a ripple effect across other headers. Only forcing recompilation of a cpp file is the lighter touch.

You are correct, by the way. Adding a value to an enum could possibly cause it to take a different amount of space. Which is why forward declaration as I suggest requires the ":int" or any other similar data type you care for (char, unsigned short, etc.) as that guarantees it will always take the same space, which is what is needed to pass it into a function; knowledge of space it will take, not contents.