# What steps can be taken to reduce link time?

Tags: c++, linker, reduce, build-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to improve link performance for a large C++ application in VS2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143808/how-to-improve-link-performance-for-a-large-c-application-in-vs2005)

We are building against Visual Studio 7.1, and have two main dlls.

DLL A is 7Mb, and DLL B is 5Mb – However DLL B Takes far longer than A.

What should I look for?

There are many tips about reducing compile time, however I'm not sure what ones there are to reduce link time.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143808/how-to-improve-link-performance-for-a-large-c-application-in-vs2005 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364240/how-do-you-reduce-compile-time-and-linking-time-for-visual-c-projects-native ?